# First two Server Sent Events not being received after a page refresh

Tags: python, reactjs, fastapi, addeventlistener, server-sent-events

I have been working on a project that detects the insertion and removal of USB-serial devices (ttyUSB_), when a device is detected an API written in Python using FastAPI sends an event using starlette_sse. I then have a React page that receives this event, and will display the device when connected and remove the device when disconnected.

When the page is initially loaded or refreshed, it's as if the eventlistener fails to listen for the first two events. I can see on the server side that the event is being sent, but the eventlistener is not entering the correct path. After these first two events, everything works flawlessly until the page is reloaded again and this behavior resumes.

React

```
useEffect(() => {
    const evtSource = new EventSource("http://localhost:3700/stream");
    
    evtSource.addEventListener("new_device", function (event) {
        console.log(event.data)
        setMessage((messages) => [...messages, event.data]);
  });
  
    evtSource.addEventListener("remove_device", function (event) {
        console.log('remove requested')
        handleRemove(event.data)
  });

    evtSource.addEventListener("end_event", function (event) {
        setMessage((messages) => [...messages, event.data]);
  });

    return () => 
        evtSource.close()
    
}, []);
```

Python

```
@app.get("/stream")
async def message_stream(request: Request):
    async def event_generator():
        while True:
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                logger.debug("Request disconnected")
                break
            
            devices = detect_new_device()
            if devices:
                if 'add' in devices:
                    yield {
                        "event": "new_device",
                        "id": "message_id",
                        "retry": messageStreamRetryTimeout,
                        "data": devices['add']
                    }
                elif 'remove' in devices:
                    tempDev = pastDeviceDict.get(devices['remove'])
                    del pastDeviceDict[devices['remove']]
                    yield {
                        "event": "remove_device",
                        "id": "message_id",
                        "retry": messageStreamRetryTimeout,
                        "data": tempDev
                    }
            else:
                yield {
                    "event": "end_event",
                    "id": "message_id",
                    "retry": messageStreamRetryTimeout,
                    "data": "End of the stream"
                }
    return EventSourceResponse(event_generator())
```

I feel that the issue has to be on the React end, as I get confirmation via print statements that I am at least hitting the yield statements for both of the events that are not received.

Comment: @AdesojiAlu Can you elaborate?